# How to determine if next page exists with searchAfter query param of ElasticSearchRequest

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, opensearch

1. We have a load more button on UI which requests for next pages. We have used SearchAfter query param to implement ES Pagination
2. I am using sortValues present in ElasticSearch Response to generate nextPageToken.
3. I found a scenario where even though next page didn't exists, I am getting sort values in Elastic search response and when I queries ES with that sort values it returns empty response.
4. What should I do to avoid this scenario? Can I determine in advance whether next page exists or not?
5. Another thing coming into my mind is can we assume if ES response size is less than requested size means we don't have any new pages?

//SearchRequest code snippet

```
final SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
                .query(query)
                .fetchSource(getSessionsQuery.getColumns().toArray(String[]::new), null)
                .size(getSessionsQuery.getResultSize())
                .sort(new FieldSortBuilder(route.getTechnologyConfiguration().get(TIMESTAMP_FIELD_KEY)).order(SortOrder.ASC))
                .sort(new FieldSortBuilder(route.getTechnologyConfiguration().get(VERSION_SORT_KEY)).order(SortOrder.DESC));

        if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(getSessionsQuery.getNextToken())) {
            final String[] tokens = getSessionsQuery.getNextToken().split(ES_SORT_FIELD_DELIMITER);
            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                sourceBuilder.searchAfter(tokens);
            }
        }

        return new SearchRequest().indices(route.getTechnologyConfiguration().get(INDEX_KEY)).source(sourceBuilder);
```

//code snippet to generate next page token

```
 if (hits[hits.length - 1].getSortValues().length > 0) {
                    final String esSortFieldToken = Joiner.on(ES_SORT_FIELD_DELIMITER).join(hits[hits.length - 1].getSortValues());
                    nextPageToken = Joiner.on(NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN_DELIMITER).join(route.getRouteName(), esSortFieldToken);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can assume that there are no more pages when you get less than `size` (or zero) hits back.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach is only approximate-- it gives false results if the size of your total result set happens to be an exact multiple of the page size. For example, if you have 100 results in pages of 10, the 10th page will have 10 results and you'll generate a false, empty 11th page.

Comment: @Nentuaby that's true. Though, if this is a significant UX issue, you can request 11 docs, only display 10 of them, and stop pagination when you get back less than 11 docs.

Answer (score 2):

One trick to figure out whether or not there's another page of results is to request one more result from Elasticsearch than you're displaying on the page (e.g. if your UI has a page size showing 10 results, request 11 results from Elasticsearch). Then if you get the number of results you requested, you'll know for sure that there's another page of results without needing to make an additional query. If you get less than the number of results requested, you'll know there are no more.